# How to take snapshots of specific indices in Elastic Cloud Enterprise?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud, elasticsearch-snapshot

In Elastic Cloud UI, You can take snapshots/backup of your entire on-disk data and store it in a file shared system, say, Object Store S3.

How do I backup only certain indices instead of all with using Elastic Cloud UI only? Is there a way?

If not then and only then I want to go with APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you link out to the Elasticsearch Service docs for [Snapshot and Restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-snapshot-restore.html), you will see that we also link to the Elasticsearch [Snapshot and Restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/snapshot-restore.html) docs. Here you will find instructions to backup certain indices. You can use the [API console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-api-console.html) to do this more easily through the Elastic Cloud UI.